# Detect keyboard event in Internet Explorer in React

Tags: reactjs, internet-explorer, mouseevent, keyboard-events

Although the below function is meant to be triggered on `Mouse` click, it is also triggered upon placing the cursor on a column and hitting `Enter`, in all other browsers except `Internet Explorer`

How can I get the below function to be invoked upon keyboard `Enter` on `Internet Explorer` as well, the end goal being that, in all browsers, placing the mouse on the column and clicking it, or placing the cursor on the column and hitting `Enter` both cause the `_onColumnClick` function to be triggered ?

```
private _onColumnClick(column: IColumn, ev: React.MouseEvent<HTMLElement>): void {
    const { onColumnClick } = this.props;

    if (column.onColumnClick) {
       column.onColumnClick(ev, column);
    }

    if (onColumnClick) {
      onColumnClick(ev, column);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please make sure that your column get focused when you click on it using mouse. Than after if press enter key than it can execute the event. If column is not in focus than event also not get fired on enter key press. With your above code we cannot produce the issue. you can try to provide a sample code which we can try to run directly in IE to produce the issue may help to understand the issue in better way.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT thanks for your response. Here is a codepen https://codepen.io/anon/pen/Gbmwxo?&editable=true
Please place the cursor on any of the columns and hit Enter. You will notice that it sorts the column in, say, Chrome, whereas, it does not sort in IE.

Comment: code pan is not working in a IE browser makes it harder to reproduce it.